# Can i make my cdn directly contact firebase storage with the token then return the file only not the token?

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, firebase-storage, cdn

So I need `cdn.ex.com/avatars/:UserID` point to my cloud private file URI which is `https://cloudapi.com/account.cloud.com/files/uploads/avatars/(userid)/avatar.png?token=${genNewTok()}` (true URL is put)
I don't have any code yet except

```js
app.get('/avatars/:userid', (req, res)=>{
    let userid = req.params.userid
    let uri = `https://cloudapi.com/account.cloud.com/files/uploads/avatars/${userid}/avatar.png?token=${genNewTok()}`

});
```

So I shall be able to do in html:

```html
<span>Username</span>
<img class="pfp" src="cdn.ex.com/avatars/671856275627525">
```

Instead of having to do

```html
<span>Username</span>
<img class="pfp" src="https://cloudapi.com/account.cloud.com/files/uploads/avatars/671856275627525/avatar.png">
```

Any help on how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.
You need to access the metadata.metadata.firebasetokenthingy
and add it to the uri.